# Store login status and user rights in the session?

Tags: php, session

just wanna know whats best practice in terms of sessions / login status / user rights?

Do you save the login status in the session like this?

```
$_SESSION['user_logged_in'] = true;
```

Do you see there any problems to do this?

Similar question with user rights?

```
$_SESSION['user_right'] = 17;
```

Save this in the session or determine it from the db on each request?

Thank you a lot!

Answer (score 0):

For your second question .i.e  :**user rights**

If you save `user rights` in session then it is beneficial until `user_right` not updated(like from admin panel). As it will minimize  request from db for each request.

But if user logged in and at that time if his `user rights` changed then it will not effect until he logged in again